Multi User Computer - Different Permissions
Originally brought up in this thread, I have an issue in where I have multiple users using the same computer and am needing to manage access permissions.
Due to file sizes, I am having specific project folders always downloaded. The majority of these files are accessible by all users, hence we have Sharepoint synced to a common folder in order to save space and sync downtime. This has become an issue on one computer as one of the users has permissions to additional folders. These additional folders are accessible by everyone through File Explorer in the same locaiton as the project folders mentioned previously... I tried changing Windows folder permissions to only allow read access to the relevant people, but get an error saying that I am unable to change any of the permissions of the contained files. I have also been unable to find a way to sync these folders to a seperate user-restricted location...
Ling.
